# Onboarding to new role - collection of PII

Tags: onboarding

I recently started a new role and received some forms today from HR. They want me to print the forms, fill them in and send them back via email.

The forms ask for pretty sensitive information including SSN and salary.

Is this a safe way to collect this information?

Comment: Debating how secure "email" may or may not be is probably not suitable for this site. However, if you have concerns, why don't you suggest that you will post the forms back with recorded/signed delivery? Or drop them off yourself if the journey isn't too far.

Comment: Wait, are you saying a physical delivery to an office (not to a specific person) is more secure than a directed e-mail?

Comment: Are you worrying about whether HR is violating any privacy laws, or are you worried about your personal data?

Comment: Weird that **HR** are asking you your salary. What happens if you say ".... one *trillion* dollars" ?

Comment: @AakashM Sounds like the company is asking OP to fill in tax documents; it's not uncommon for the applicant to fill in the information for their own tax documents, although usually the "base salary" field is filled in for you.  Also, filling in "one trillion dollars" on a tax form is not likely to go the way you want ;-)

Answer (score 5):

If you are uncomfortable with the current method that HR is using for gathering this information you can always ask for an alternative method.  Just be prepared for them to say no.  If they say no, then you will need to decide if not providing this information is worth losing this job over.

This all assumes that you are legitimately being onboarded to a legitimate company rather than a scam.  Some companies are more professional than others when it comes to handling PII but there is no 100% safe way to gather/handle PII.

Answer (score -4):

No, email is not secure. HR should not be relying email for sensitive information. I do not believe that using email meets the privacy requirements of HIPAA. I know of lawyers and therapists who do not use email any more. HR would do well to get a system for filling out that information online with a secure server. (Disclaimer: I have built such a system.)

But a scanned image of the forms is (edit delete: much) more secure than text email. Most attempts to gain information from emails look at text. Turns out that there are plenty of places that put sensitive information in emails and send that out to the wrong locations. A brief survey of such wrong emails has included very sensitive business information, many bank messages, and quite personal messages being sent to the wrong person.

Edit: Here is what HHS.gov says about email and PII https://www.hhs.gov/hipaa/for-professionals/faq/570/does-hipaa-permit-health-care-providers-to-use-email-to-discuss-health-issues-with-patients/index.html
and here is what a compliancy company says about email
https://compliancy-group.com/hipaa-email-rules-hipaa-compliant-email/

Comment: "No, email is not secure" <- citation needed, or more specifically what's the threat you're trying to protect against? If you're using either (say) Outlook/Exchange or GMail, your content is end-to-end encrypted, and at that point it's probably as secure as a home-grown "secure" server.

Comment: "But a scanned image of the forms is much more secure than text email." - This is false.  If a malicious party has access to your text based emails they also have access to your attachments to those emails.  "But a scanned image of the forms is much more secure than text email." - Strange my doctor's office just asked for signed forms that contained my PII.  I of course declined that offer and will submit them in the office despite their objections.

Comment: @PhilipKendall gmail is reported to be not secure on their servers. Google is reported to scan emails to be able to send targeted ads. They have complied with government orders to deliver emails. Outlook does not encrypt email by default. Here an HR department doesn't even suggest turning on encryption of PII emails.

Comment: @Donald and Philip Kendall, How would you edit this to show under what conditions emails and attachments are secure? And what would this HR department have to change to receive secure email?

Comment: Microsoft Note can search text in images... there is zero security benefit to sending a picture rather than a text email. It is not difficult to extract text from an image that a human can read.

Comment: "Does the HIPAA Privacy Rule permit health care providers to use e-mail to discuss health issues and treatment with their patients? // Yes." So what is the basis for your claim that "I do not believe that using email meets the privacy requirements of HIPAA"?

Comment: @DavidR - Emails are not secure unless you encrypt them.  An attachment to an encrypted email cannot be accessed without accessing the encrypted email.

Comment: @PhilipKendall Read that again. Health care providers can discuss health issues, but not send PII over email. Thus, the claim stands that email is not considered secure for transmission of PII per HIPAA rules.

Comment: Why are we talking about HIPAA at all? Nothing in the original question indicates this is health related information. The rules around protection of your SSN are different. [Though the Social Security number is a federal identifier, states have authority over how they’re handled, which means the protocols vary. Currently just 12 states restrict the physical mailing of Social Security numbers, but no states ban emailing them.](https://time.com/4344632/social-security-number-email-fraud-identity-theft-encryption/). (from 2016, so that # may be different now)

Comment: @ColleenV If the business has no dealings with employee health information such as the business does not offer health insurance, then the HIPAA rules do not apply.

Comment: @ColleenV - I have no idea why anyone brought up HIPAA.  However, email is still insecure, and that includes "scanned text" if attached to a plain text email.  PII shouldn't be sent over email, period, and SSN is considered to be PII.

Comment: @Donald You're preaching to the choir.